# String with at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one special char, one digit and one white space

Tags: regex, perl

I want a script to select a username. The rules for selecting a username are:

- The minimum length of the username must be 5 characters and the maximum may be 10.
- It should contain at least one letter from A-Z
- It should contain at least one digit from 0-9
- It should contain at least one character from amongst @#*=
- It should not contain any spaces.

I have tried this:

```
if (( length $passwd[$i]<=10 && length $passwd[$i]>=5 && $passwd[$i] =~ /.*\p{Lu}/ && $passwd[$i] =~ tr/0-9//cd  && $passwd[$i] =~ /[a-z]/ ))
{   
    print "PASS\n";
}
else
{
    print "FAIL\n";
}
```

Comment: Why call the variable $passwd when it contain a username?

Comment: I'm sorry for using $passwd, its just like that. And i also did not attempt to find whitespace also.

Comment: A single regexp is probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one perl regular expression, that could be:

```
if ($username =~ qr{^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#*=])(?!.* ).{5,10}$}s) ...
```

Or:

```
if ($username =~ qr{^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#*=])[^ ]{5,10}$}s)
```

Comment: thank you sir. its working in command promt. but how can i use it in my script. i am like two days old in perl. so please be co-operative. i know i somehow asking very silly question..

Comment: Your regex says `Perl #42` is OK.

Comment: @Kenosis, oops thanks, `(?!=` should have been `(?!`. Fixed now.

Comment: Yes--well done.  You can omit the `/s` modifier, as it's used to treat a newline-containing string as a **s** ingle string, where the metacharacter `.` would then match `\n`.

Comment: @Kenosis, which is why I used `s`, or otherwise they would say that `"Abc\n9#"` is not a valid username.

Comment: Hmm...  Perhaps the OP's specs are not so clear, since I can't see that `"Abc\n9#"` *should* be a valid user name.  That is, I wonder if (white)spaces was intended, as `"Abc\t\r\n9#"`, etc., would be valid.  For example, `"Perl\x0E#42"` is valid, but contains a [vertical tab](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-design-and-development/0596102356/data-integrity-and-security/web2apps-chp-5-sect-4).  Regardless, given the OP's specs, your regex does the job well (+1).